# Getting a crash in map destructor stl_map.h while deleting class member map

Tags: c++, dictionary, crash, destructor, delete-operator

I have a class which has map member variable and in class destructor I am deleteing the 
map member by calling a wrapper function reset() as shown in below code

```
void zreg::reset()
 83 {
 84     s_err = "";
 85     bad_types = 0;
 86     bad_apis = 0;
 87     b_valid = false;
 88 
 89     zt_itr_t it;
 90     while ((it = m_types.begin()) != m_types.end()) {
 91     delete it->second;
 92     m_types.erase(it);
 93     }
 94 
 95     zf_itr_t itf;
 96     while ((itf = m_apis.begin()) != m_apis.end()) {
 97     delete itf->second;
 98     m_apis.erase(itf);
 99     }
100 }

 36 zreg::~zreg()
 37 {
 38     reset();
 39 }



class zreg
210 {
211 public:
212     //  Construction/destruction
213     zreg();
214     ~zreg();
215 
216     typedef std::map<std::string, z_type_info *> zt_map_t;
217     typedef std::map<std::string, z_type_info *>::iterator zt_itr_t;
218     typedef std::map<std::string, z_type_info *>::const_iterator zt_citr_t;
219     typedef std::map<std::string, z_type_function *> zf_map_t;
220     typedef std::map<std::string, z_type_function *>::iterator zf_itr_t;
221     typedef std::map<std::string, z_type_function *>::const_iterator zf_citr_t;
222 

255 private:
256     size_t bad_types;
257     size_t bad_apis;
258     std::string s_err;
259     std::string s_version;
260     bool b_valid;
261 
262     zt_map_t m_types;
263     zf_map_t m_apis;
```

In above z_type_info  and z_type_function  is a class

stack trace:
    #0  std::map, std::allocator >, z_type_function*, std::less, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator > const, z_type_function*> > >::~map (this=0x8006da400, __in_chrg=)
        at /x/freebsd/x86_64/stdhdrs_cplus/bits/stl_map.h:94
    #1  0x0000000804ea34c2 in zreg::~zreg (this=0x805158ac0, __in_chrg=)

As seen from bt that the last function called is ~zreg destructor but why the bt is not showing a call to reset() function being called.

secondly how to reproduce this crash as I am not able to reproduce it again. probably if I take the code of my class zreg out should it will reproduce the issue?

Comment: Is the problem is I am not doing the iterator it and itf increment in reset function while deleting the member . And may be some null check missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think crash happened after you reset(), in ~map()
It may be if memory of you zreg instance was corrupted in other place.

Comment: But in backtrace(bt) of gdb a call to reset() function is not shown after ~zreg destructor called.